# How to find the Array with the longest string length inside a multi dimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

**Hi guys !
I have an multi-dimension array like this :**

```
$arr = 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            ['id'] => 1
            ['title'] => one test
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            ['id'] => 4
            ['title'] => two test xyz
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            ['id'] => 2
            ['title'] => fdfdf dfdfdffdfdf
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            ['id'] => 3
            ['title'] => fddddđ fffffffff ssss
        )

)
```

Is there any way let get longest string and its length in any `$array['title']` element ?
I want to get "fddddđ fffffffff ssss" and its length.
Please tell me any way let : get longest string , get longest length string and both. Thanks .

I see a way : `max(array_map('strlen', $ary));`
<== but it use for single array , 
in this topic i want there is any way let just find in $arr['title']

**Update :**

but if i want to get :

1. longest length string + longest string inside `$arr['title']`
2. largest "id" value number inside `$arr['id']` , largest "id" value number now is 4 inside $arr[1]['id']

**<== and all them are assigned to a new array like :**

```
    array(
         'id' => 4,
         'title' => 'fddddđ fffffffff ssss'
)
```

How to i do ?
Look carefully my update before you answer , thank

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: hey guys , i updated new problem , help me , thank

Comment: Look carefully new update before you answer , thank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$max = '';
$maxlen = 0;

foreach ($arr as $elm) {
    $len = strlen($elm['title']);

    if ($len > $maxlen) {
        $maxlen = $len;
        $max = $elm['title'];
    }
}

echo "The longest string is \"$max\" and it is $maxlen chars long.\n";
```

Comment: Nice, same here. clean and simple!

Comment: hey you , i updated new problem , help me , thank

Answer (score 1):

This is a version that will iterate over a multidimensional array and return the array of longest string it finds. Adapted on Sean Bright's code to keep things simple.

```
 $arr = array(

    "0" => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'title' => "one test"
        ),

    "1" => array(
            'id' => 2,
            'title' => "two test xyz"
        ),

    "2" => array(
            'id' => 3,
            'title' => "fdfdf dfdfdffdfdf"
        ),

    "3" => array(
            'id' => 4,
            'title' => "fddddđ fffffffff ssss"
       )

);

function longest_string(&$arr, &$max='',&$maxlen=false){

    foreach ($arr as $elm=>$val) {
        $len = strlen($val);



       if ($len > $maxlen) {

            $maxlen = $len;
            $max = $arr;
        }

        if( is_array($val) ){
            longest_string($val, $max, $maxlen);
        }

    }

    return $max;
}

echo  var_dump(longest_string($arr1));

// array(2) { ["id"]=> int(4) ["title"]=> string(22) "fddddđ fffffffff ssss" }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$maxlen = 0;
$idxMax = null;

foreach($arr as $idx => $elem) {
  if(strlen($elem['title']) > $maxlen)
    $idxMax = $idx;
}

printf('Longest string: "%s" (%d), at index %d',
  $arr[$idxMax]['title'],
  strlen($arr[$idxMax]['title']),
  $idxMax);
```

To answer your updated question, use `$arr[$idxMax]['id']`. If you want the array containing the string and its index, simply assign it to a new variable:

```
$longestEntry = $arr[$idxMax];
```

To combine the highest ID with the longest string, use:

```
$maxlen = 0;
$maxId = $arr[0]['id']; // assuming array has at least one element
$idxMax = null;

foreach($arr as $idx => $elem) {
  if(strlen($elem['title']) > $maxlen)
    $idxMax = $idx;

  $maxId = max($elem['id'], $maxId);
}

$max = array(
  'id' => $maxId,
  'title' => $arr[$idxMax],
);
```

Comment: hey you , i updated new problem , help me , thank

Comment: I really suggest you to read a PHP crash course. You should be able to answer your question(s) with a bit of searching or digging through manuals, they are anything but different problems.

Comment: $longestEntry = $arr[$idxMax]; <== no , please look carefully my update , $arr[1]['id'] = 4 is max , while $arr[3]['id'] is not max but $arr[3]['title'] is max title ==> and i want all them are assigned in a new array

Comment: Look carefully before you answer , thank

Comment: What's the point? That's two unrelated values in a single array. But anyway, you will find your answer in one of the other answers

Comment: That's two unrelated values in a single array <== good , that is my mean. Thank for your code :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $string="";
    foreach($arr as $list)
    {
      $string=strlen(list['title'])>strlen($string)?ist['title']:$string;

    }
    echo $string;
    echo strlen($string)

you can find largest string also string length try it
```

Comment: hey you , i updated new problem , help me , thank